# What does teleportation have to do w/ XOR linked lists?

Tags: cryptography, teleportation

I am trying to wrap my head around the correlation between [repeating](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4183/2645) [teleportation](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4127/2645) & [XOR linked lists](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2352/2645).

I understand that:

1. "the quantum equivalent of the one time pad (i.e. [XORing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4125/2645) a message with a secret key) is quantum teleportation" ([source](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4125/quantum-xor-cipher-construction#comment4566_4125))
2. "the simplest way to generalize teleportation is to just repeat it" ([source](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4216/2645))

What I don't understand is how repeating teleportation could lead to "a data structure which is used to maintain a list of data items" (see [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2573/2645) for more use cases for quantum XOR linked lists).

Hopefully someone can help me to understand how these concepts connect, because I do *not* understand teleportation well enough to see how it could be used to accomplish any of the use cases described in the answer to my XOR linked list question.

See also: [Equivalent Quantum Circuits](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2998) sections VII. A & B

> As example applications we study quantum teleportation and dense coding protocols in terms of a simple XOR swapping circuit and give an intuitive picture of a basic gate teleportation circuit.

Comment: I'm not sure why you suppose that teleportation would be relevant to quantum XOR-linked lists. Is it just because XOR is involved in both cases?

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Beyond XOR being involved, it seems like a XOR linked list correlates w/ a chained XOR cipher (which has been stated to be equivalent to teleportation). I suppose the underlying question I have is how teleportation (or if it isn't teleportation what gate(s)) can be used to execute a XOR linked list. (Also contemplating [XOR swapping](http://algassert.com/post/1717) in correlation w/ link traversal & uncomputation)

Comment: It would appear that an "XOR cipher" (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) is a Vernham-like cipher, and not really anything that I would consider to be like an XOR-linked list. Chaining XOR ciphers would also seem to yield just a different XOR cipher, albeit with slightly different features. In an XOR linked list, the things which are XORed are memory addresses of forward and reverse links: it is not immediately clear why you might want to encrypt them unless you have a particular use case in mind; and it is unclear what role the list structure itself is playing.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap What if you wanted to encrypt whatever was being teleported? Eg. in a blind computing scenario, or for a secure communications channel. I am considering XOR linked lists for [logical clocks](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4990/2645) (where previous would indicate local time & next would indicate what is known about global time - possibly correlating w/ eigenvalues of [clock and shift matrices](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4989/2645)) for a [time entangled blockchain](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2366/2645)

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap I would also like to be able to generalize the logical clock (XOR linked list, n qudit teleportations, whatever is clever) system upwards to vector & matrix clocks for use in a distributed system.

Comment: Just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33259001) which references that XOR linked lists & XOR ciphers build upon the [XOR swap](http://algassert.com/post/1717) concept