# Can someone elaborate how to use Qutrits to do teleportation? And the unitary operation Bob needs to do?

Tags: quantum-gate, entanglement, teleportation, communication, quantum-state

I can understand doing teleportation by using qubits, however, I am stuck there when it comes to qutrits and the operation Bob needs to perform. Suppose Alice and Bob are sharing the most entangled states in the beginning ie:$\frac{1}{\sqrt3}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle+|22\rangle)$ and teleport a qutrit $|\psi\rangle=a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle+c|2\rangle$.

Like how to get the 9 bell states? [image]

And if the outcome is |ψ10⟩ Then what should Bob do?

Comment: this is a bit broad. What exactly do you currently understand about it? what is your current understanding of the overall topic?

Comment: Welcome to QCSE! You can use the [quantum fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fourier_transform) to obtain these states. Also, see [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4989/generalizing-quantum-teleportation-for-qudits) for a good description of qudit teleportation.