# What's the state-of-the-art to calculate $|Ab\rangle$, given a matrix $|A\rangle$ and a vector $|b\rangle$ in QRAM encoding

Tags: simulation, hamiltonian-simulation, unitarity, linear-algebra

Assuming that we have a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ stored in a quantum superposition, i.e.
$$|A\rangle= \frac{1}{\|A\|_F}\sum_{i,j=0}^{n-1}{a_{ij}}|i,j\rangle$$
and a vector $b\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ stored in
$$|b\rangle= \frac{1}{\|b\|}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{b_{i}}|i\rangle.$$

How can I find a unitary, such that

$$U|b\rangle\approx|Ab\rangle?$$

Comment: Hi @Thommy257. I removed the LaTeX in the title as it was not adding more than what plain text could convey.

Comment: @AdrienSuau is there a reason for that? Latex in titles is perfectly fine, and I'd argue it looks much better than the corresponding text-based alternatives

Comment: I think I remember a time where uneeded LaTeX in title was removed, mostly to ease text-based research, but I might be wrong. In any case, I agree that the LaTeX was looking way better, re-viewing my edit it seems I got a little too quick. I'll revert, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @AdrienSuau no worries. In fairness this was raised on meta in the early days of the site, see https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/180/55, but honestly on math-based sites latex in titles is completely standard at this point

Comment: This exactly what I was thinking about, I did not search it but I remember reading this discussion a while back.

Comment: Are you looking for a quantum algorithm for matrix-vector multiplication? I don't think there exists one that is significantly better than classical multiplication. (This paper seems to propose something https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.01601.) Or are you asking for any possibility to do this (including classical methods)?

Answer (score 4):

I do not know what the state-of-the-art for this problem is, but here is my attempt at it.

First, I doubt whether the required unitary $U$ can be found for every matrix $A$. The most glaring issue occurs when $b\in\ker A$. In this case, $|Ab\rangle$ is ill-defined, so it is not clear what $U|b\rangle$ should be approximately equal to. A slightly more subtle issue concerns the preservation of the inner product. Consider for example $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ and $b_1=(1, 0)^T$ and $b_2=(1, 1)^T$. Then $|b_1\rangle = |0\rangle$, $|b_2\rangle = |+\rangle$ and $|Ab_1\rangle = |0\rangle$, $|Ab_2\rangle = (|0\rangle + 2|1\rangle)/\sqrt{5}$. However, for any unitary $U$ we have

$$
\langle b_1|U^\dagger U|b_2\rangle = \langle b_1|b_2\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

which is hard to regard as approximately equal to

$$
\langle Ab_1|Ab_2\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}.
$$

Such issues may be resolved by using the context in which the problem arises to place additional restrictions on $A$ and $b$. Alternatively, we can widen the search for the required transformation beyond the unitary operations. The latter is what we do below.

### Matrix multiplication by teleportation with post-selection

We prepare the state $|Ab\rangle$ by teleporting the state $|b\rangle$ through the state $|A\rangle$ and post-selecting on a measurement outcome.

Suppose we have three subsystems $K$, $L$ and $M$ each with Hilbert space of dimension $n$. First, prepare the subsystem $K$ in the state $|b\rangle=\frac{1}{\|b\|}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|k\rangle_K$ and the subsystems $L$ and $M$ in the joint state $|A\rangle=\frac{1}{\|A\|_F}\sum_{m,l=0}^{n-1}a_{ml}|l\rangle_L|m\rangle_M$. Now, measure subsystems $K$ and $L$ in the Fourier basis

$$
|\Psi_{u,v}\rangle_{KL} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} (X^u Z^v \otimes I) \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} |j\rangle_K|j\rangle_L\tag1
$$

where $X$ and $Z$ are the generalization of the Pauli operators to $n$-dimensional Hilbert space known as the [shift and clock matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Construction:_The_clock_and_shift_matrices) and given by $X|j\rangle = |j + 1 \mod n\rangle$ and $Z|j\rangle = e^{\frac{2\pi ij}{n}}|j\rangle$. See [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4993/10480) for a good description of qudit teleportation.

Each possible measurement outcome is described by a pair of numbers $u, v \in \{0, 1, \dots, n-1\}$. Suppose that the measurement outcome is $u=0, v=0$. Then the subsystem $M$ is in the state

$$
\begin{align}
_{KL}\langle\Psi_{0,0}|b\rangle_K|A\rangle_{LM} &=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{}_K\langle k| {}_L\langle k|\right) |b\rangle_K|A\rangle_{LM}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{}_K\langle k|b\rangle_K\, {}_L\langle k|A\rangle_{LM} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{b_k}{\|b\|} \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \frac{a_{lk}}{\|A\|_F}|l\rangle_M \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\|b\|\|A\|_F}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{lk}b_k|l\rangle_M \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\|b\|\|A\|_F}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} (Ab)_l|l\rangle_M \\
&=\frac{\|Ab\|}{\sqrt{n}\|b\|\|A\|_F}|Ab\rangle_M
\end{align}\tag2
$$

which after normalization becomes $|Ab\rangle$ as promised. For other measurement outcomes the subsystem $M$ is not in the state $|Ab\rangle$ due to the operators $X$ and $Z$ in $(1)$. In some applications it may be possible to boost success probability by applying a correction based on the measurement outcome $u, v$ to obtain $|Ab\rangle$. However, this part of the protocol depends on properties of $A$ and $b$.

---

It is interesting to consider what happens in certain special cases. For example, consider the situation where $b \in \ker A$. In this case, the state $|Ab\rangle$ is ill-defined and from $(2)$ we see that the probability of obtaining the required $u=0,v=0$ measurement outcome is zero.

Another interesting case occurs when $A=aa^T$ is a rank one matrix and $a^Tb\ne 0$. Then $|A\rangle_{LM}=|a\rangle_L|a\rangle_M$ is a product state and nothing can be teleported through it. However in this case

$$
|aa^Tb\rangle = \frac{1}{\|aa^Tb\|}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k a^Tb |k\rangle
= \frac{a^Tb}{|a^Tb|}|a\rangle \equiv |a\rangle
$$

and the initial state is the appropriate output state up to the unobservable global phase.

Comment: Adam reaches 5000!