# Can we teleport an arbitrary two-qubit state?

Tags: qiskit, teleportation

Can we teleport a quantum register $a\left|00\right> + b\left|01\right> + c\left|10\right> + d\left|11\right>$ ? How can I visualize the output for this? I was looking at the https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/teleportation.html. What changes do I need to do this?

Comment: Relevant post: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4989/12988

Comment: the teleportation protocol works for states of arbitrary dimension (though of course you'll also need a suitable large entangled state as resource)

Comment: I think the textbook link you post already answers your question, so I am not sure what you want to visualize.