# How does quantum teleportation relate to quantum encryption?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, teleportation

I am in grade 11 and am trying to work on a project, but I find this question a little confusing. I am trying to talk about the implications of quantum teleportation, specifically quantum encryption but I have not found a good source to help me understand how they are related. Also, if you have any other cool implications of quantum teleportation please share! Thanks.

Comment: You might find these questions interesting: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4125/quantum-xor-cipher-construction & https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4991/what-does-teleportation-have-to-do-w-xor-linked-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question reads like quantum encryption is a special example of quantum teleportation, which is not the case.

Teleportation solves the following problem:  Alice wants to send Bob a qubit, but has no way to physically transport it without destroying it.  However, Alice and Bob already share an entangled state, and they can communicate classically.  They can use quantum teleportation to get the qubit to Bob without transporting any physical qubits.

For encryption, Alice and Bob simply want to communicate some classical bits without being eavesdropped on without their knowledge.  For quantum key distribution, is it not important whether the quantum states are sent to Bob in some physical mail system or via teleportation.  The system is secure against an evil postman who opens the package to read or modify it.